# How to convert a series of objects into datetimes, considering also UTC

Tags: python, timezone

I have a DataFrame column (named 'DateTime'), containing a time sequence with a timestep of one minute. They are objects. Each object has this format:

```
2018-01-10 00:00:00+01:00

2018-01-10 00:01:00+01:00

2018-01-10 00:02:00+01:00

..

2019-02-04 23:57:00+01:00

2019-02-04 23:58:00+01:00

2019-02-04 23:59:00+01:00
```

I need to convert them into datetime, so that to get date and time. How can i do that?

I tried this code:

```
data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DateTime'])

data['Date'] = data['DateTime'].dt.date

data['Time'] = data['DateTime'].dt.time
```

But i got the following error:

> 'ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to
>   datetime64 unless utc=True'

Comment: Try: data['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['DateTime'], utc=True), for me it works also without utc=True

Comment: I also have the datetimes automatically converted to UTC even without specifying utc=True. `'1994-01-07 19:30:00+01:00'` is converted to `Timestamp('1994-01-07 18:30:00')`. So, I can't see why it wouldn't work. Maybe you're on an older version of pandas?

Comment: i don't know but the suggestion worked, i think it may be due to the fact that the date range i need to convert includes the change of time from solar to legal